# Angular 2 Hover event

Tags: javascript, angular, events, hover

In the new **Angular2** framework, does anyone know the proper way to do a hover like an event?

In **Angular1** there was `ng-Mouseover`, but that doesn't seem to have been carried over.

I've looked through the docs and haven't found anything.

Comment: It's just onmouseover.

Comment: check this page https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: I think `mousemove` event can also help here. [SEE THIS PAGE FOR EXAMPLE](https://lishman.io/angular-2-event-binding)

Answer (score 316, accepted):

If you want to perform a hover like event on any HTML element, then you can do it like this.

**HTML**

```html
 <div (mouseenter) ="mouseEnter('div a') "  (mouseleave) ="mouseLeave('div A')">
        <h2>Div A</h2>
 </div> 
 <div (mouseenter) ="mouseEnter('div b')"  (mouseleave) ="mouseLeave('div B')">
        <h2>Div B</h2>
 </div>
```

**Component**

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'basic-detail',
    templateUrl: 'basic.component.html',
})
export class BasicComponent{

   mouseEnter(div : string){
      console.log("mouse enter : " + div);
   }

   mouseLeave(div : string){
     console.log('mouse leave :' + div);
   }
}
```

You should use both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events in order to fully implement functional hover events in angular 2.

Comment: how can I trigger it from angular component .ts file ?

Comment: @mayurkukadiya see my updated answer below -https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688325/5043867

Comment: Simple solution so I give it +1

Comment: @MayurKukadiya Simply define a boolean varibale lets say booleanVariable: boolean = false; variable with initial value to false; In mouseEnter() function just assign boolean variable to true and mouseLeave() function assign that boolean varible to false. Finally using *ngIf="booleanVariable" in the div to access it completely.

Answer (score 133):

yes there is `on-mouseover` in angular2 instead of `ng-Mouseover` like in angular 1.x so you have to write this :-

```html
<div on-mouseover='over()' style="height:100px; width:100px; background:#e2e2e2">hello mouseover</div>

over(){
    console.log("Mouseover called");
  }
```

As @Gunter Suggested in comment there is alternate of `on-mouseover` we can use this too. Some people prefer the on- prefix alternative, known as the canonical form.

## Update

HTML Code -

```html
<div (mouseover)='over()' (mouseout)='out()' style="height:100px; width:100px; background:#e2e2e2">hello mouseover</div>
```

Controller/.TS Code -

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  over(){
    console.log("Mouseover called");
  }

  out(){
    console.log("Mouseout called");
  }
}
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mouseevent?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Some other Mouse events can be used in Angular -

```
(mouseenter)="myMethod()"
(mousedown)="myMethod()"
(mouseup)="myMethod()"
```

Comment: Why not `<div (mouseover)='over()'`? ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Is their some sort of list of all events? I looked on the angular 2 site and could not find (mouseover)

Comment: These are not Angular events but browser events.

Comment: Clearly this is the way, but does anyone have a link to the Angular documentation for this? I feel like it's super abstract and sparse. I'm just looking for a list of on-whatevers so I know what comes standard.

Comment: @Pardeep Jain, how to do add a class when hover and remove that class when mouseout?

Comment: capture the element using local variable and add classes into it. @abcidd

Answer (score 38):

You can do it with a host:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myHighlight]',
  host: {
    '(mouseenter)': 'onMouseEnter()',
    '(mouseleave)': 'onMouseLeave()'
  }
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  private _defaultColor = 'blue';
  private el: HTMLElement;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) { this.el = el.nativeElement; }

  @Input('myHighlight') highlightColor: string;

  onMouseEnter() { this.highlight(this.highlightColor || this._defaultColor); }
  onMouseLeave() { this.highlight(null); }

   private highlight(color:string) {
    this.el.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

}
```

Just adapt it to your code (found at: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html )

Answer (score 24):

If you are interested in the mouse entering or leaving one of your components you can use the `@HostListener` decorator:

```
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  @HostListener('mouseenter') 
  onMouseEnter() {
    this.highlight('yellow');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') 
  onMouseLeave() {
    this.highlight(null);
  }

...

}
```

As explained in the link in @Brandon comment to OP (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)

Answer (score 12):

Simply do `(mouseenter)` attribute in Angular2+...

In your HTML do:

```
<div (mouseenter)="mouseHover($event)">Hover!</div>
```

and in your component do:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  templateUrl: './component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.scss']
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  mouseHover(e) {
    console.log('hovered', e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If the mouse over for all over the component is your option, you can directly is `@hostListener` to handle the events to perform the mouse over al below.

```
  import {HostListener} from '@angular/core';

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.hover = true;
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.addClass = 'edit';
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.hover = false;
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.addClass = 'un-edit';
  }
```

Its available in `@angular/core`. I tested it in angular `4.x.x`

Answer (score 7):

For handling the event on overing, you can try something like this 
(it works for me):

In the Html template:

```
<div (mouseenter)="onHovering($event)" (mouseleave)="onUnovering($event)">
  <img src="../../../contents/ctm-icons/alarm.svg" class="centering-me" alt="Alerts" />
</div>
```

In the angular component:

```
    onHovering(eventObject) {
    console.log("AlertsBtnComponent.onHovering:");
    var regExp = new RegExp(".svg" + "$");

    var srcObj = eventObject.target.offsetParent.children["0"];
    if (srcObj.tagName == "IMG") {
        srcObj.setAttribute("src", srcObj.getAttribute("src").replace(regExp, "_h.svg"));       
    }

   }
   onUnovering(eventObject) {
    console.log("AlertsBtnComponent.onUnovering:");
    var regExp = new RegExp("_h.svg" + "$");

    var srcObj = eventObject.target.offsetParent.children["0"];
    if (srcObj.tagName == "IMG") {
        srcObj.setAttribute("src", srcObj.getAttribute("src").replace(regExp, ".svg"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'drag-drop',
    template: `
        <h1>Drag 'n Drop</h1>
        <div #container 
             class="container"
             (mousemove)="onMouseMove( container)">
            <div #draggable 
                 class="draggable"
                 (mousedown)="onMouseButton( container)"
                 (mouseup)="onMouseButton( container)">
            </div>
        </div>`,

})
```

http://lishman.io/angular-2-event-binding

Answer (score 1):

In your js/ts file for the html that will be hovered

```
@Output() elemHovered: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
onHoverEnter(): void {
    this.elemHovered.emit([`The button was entered!`,this.event]);
}

onHoverLeave(): void {
    this.elemHovered.emit([`The button was left!`,this.event])
}
```

In your HTML that will be hovered

```
 (mouseenter) = "onHoverEnter()" (mouseleave)="onHoverLeave()"
```

In your js/ts file that will receive info of the hovering

```
elemHoveredCatch(d): void {
    console.log(d)
}
```

In your HTML element that is connected with catching js/ts file

```
(elemHovered) = "elemHoveredCatch($event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for just a hover effect, use [`Hover.css`](https://github.com/IanLunn/Hover).

- `npm i hover.css`
- in file `angular.json` property `projects.architect.build.options.styles` --> add  this line to the array: `node_modules/hover.css/scss/hover.scss`

Use any of their classes on the element you want the effect on, i.e.:

```
<div *ngFor="let source of sources">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 hvr-glow">
            <!-- My content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```