# Cannot get ngMouseEnter (& similar commands) to work properly

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 on Angular 6, and I have a delete button that should change its icon when the mouse enters the button. However, I have tried several of these ng functions (ngMouseOver, ngMouseUp, etc.) and none of them have worked.

Here is the code:

**component.html**

```
<button type="delete" class="btn" (click)="delTr(tr)" ng- 
mouseenter="buttonHover()"><i class="{{ButtonIcon}}"></i></button>
```

**component.ts**

```
ButtonIcon: String = "far fa-trash-alt";

...

buttonHover()
{
  console.log("Mouse Enter works.") 
  this.ButtonIcon = "fas fa-trash-alt"
}
```

The console log does not output anything when the program runs, so the method `buttonHover()` is not being activated.

Also, the button icon "far fa-trash-alt" works as intended.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Look at angular-2-hover-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686772/angular-2-hover-event)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the AngularJS way - from what you said, you're using Angular(v6) so you should do it the Angular way:

`<button type="delete" class="btn" (click)="delTr(tr)" (mouseenter)="buttonEnterHover()" (mouseleave)="buttonLeaveHover()"> YourBtn </button>`

Another option would be to use the `mouseover` event:

`<button type="delete" class="btn" (click)="delTr(tr)" (mouseover)="buttonHover()"> YourBtn </button>`

Each method has its Pros and Cons, here is the Docs to help you decide which one best suites you.

- [MDN MouseEnter Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter)
- [MDN MouseOver Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had completely forgotten about the parentheses around the method name when in HTML.