# How do I assign a variable only when an element is hovered in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a bunch of divs that can be hovered.

```
<div ng-controller="HoverController as hover">
  <div class="hoverable" data-number="1"></div>
  <div class="hoverable" data-number="2"></div>
  <div class="hoverable" data-number="3"></div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is, when each .hoverable div is hovered, set the value of `hover.hoveredNumber` to the data-number attribute of the hovered element.

There must also be a condition where no element is hovered, and the value of `hover.hoveredNumber` is 0.

I've considered using ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave to manually trigger mouseover and mouseleave events for each of the hoverable divs, and from there, determine which element is hovered.

My issue is that each hoverable div also has a `:hover` style in the CSS. I understand that `:hover` is very reliable, but I don't trust the two separate mouse-detecting events to be as reliable, particularly if the user is moving their cursor very fast and one of the events is missed.

I expect there to be, at times, some discrepancy between which element is reflected in `hover.hoveredNumber` and the element that is currently displaying its `:hover`ed style. The hoverable divs are also extremely close together and overlapping in some cases, and I'm concerned that the mouseover event of one div may fire before the mouseleave event of another, causing a discrepancy.

How can I guarantee accuracy as to which element is being hovered?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686772/angular-2-hover-event

Comment: @RoqueSantos I am using AngularJS, not Angular2

Comment: well, I found another example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22532856/2721661

Comment: @RoqueSantos these answers explain what I'd need to do in order to establish mouseover and mouseleave events, but I've already got that covered - my concern is their reliability and specific timing

Comment: I understand but given those answers I see there's no hover event and the majority of people use the techniques described on those links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be responsive, avoid `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseleave`. Those directives invoke AngularJS digest cycles with large computation overhead.

Instead use a custom directive:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("detect",function() {
  return {
    link: postLink,
  }
  function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
    elem.on("mouseover mouseleave", function(e) {
      var $target = angular.element(e.target);
      var num = $target.attr("data-number") || '0';
      console.log("hover.hoveredNumber is",num);
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.hoverable {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <fieldset detect>
       <div class="hoverable" data-number="1">1</div>
       <div class="hoverable" data-number="2">2</div>
       <div class="hoverable" data-number="3">3</div>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
```

Comment: I've only dipped my toes into this AngularJS pool in which you swim.